# How do I create an object boundary in Three.js / WebGL?

Tags: graphics, 3d, three.js, webgl

I'm new to graphics and was wondering how I would go about creating an object boundary for my game.

Right now I have an object following my mouse.  This works fine for my boundary when my ship has a rotation.z of 0.  However, when I rotate the ship, the boundary has odd behavior.

I tried getting the world position of the ship and simply checking the x and y boundaries.  However, the world position seems to give me a different x and y when I rotate.  How can I 
go about creating a boundary that works for all the rotations of my ship.

Here's my game(collisions turned off for purpose of help): http://www.cis.gvsu.edu/~chaua/CS371/WebGLProject/home.html

The behavior I'd like occurs when you don't rotate the ship.
Rotate the ship with left/right mouse.

Relevant code snippets(in render loop):

```
if(mouseLeftDown)
        ship.rotation.z += leanSpeed;
if(mouseRightDown)
        ship.rotation.z += -leanSpeed;
....
....

targetX = ((lastMouseX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1) * 90;
targetY = -((lastMouseY / window.innerHeight) * 2 - 1) * 60;

var worldPosition = (new THREE.Vector3()).getPositionFromMatrix(ship.matrixWorld);

if(worldPosition.x + targetX <= (randSpawnWidth/2)-500 && worldPosition.x + targetX >= -(randSpawnWidth/2)+500)
    ship.translateX(targetX);
if(worldPosition.y + targetY <= (randSpawnHeight/2)-500 && worldPosition.y + targetY >= -(randSpawnHeight/2)+500)
    ship.translateY(targetY);
```

I would appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: I figured out a solution.  Instead of checking future positions for out of bounds before translating, I allow translating at all times.  After the translate, I check if the ship is out-of-bounds and move it back to the last in-bounds position if out-of-bounds.  This creates a bit of a shaky effect when hitting boundaries but it ensures the ship can't leave the zone.